# mongodb shards, how many mongod for this case

Tags: mongodb, distributed, database, nosql

In mongodb.
If you want to build a production system with two shards, each one a replica set with three nodes, how may mongod processes must you start?

why the answer is 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need 3 replicas per shard x the 2 shards + 3 config servers to run the sharded cluster = 9 mongods. The config servers, although also mongod processes, aren't data carrying nodes. You must have 3 config servers though, to guarantee redundancy among the config server nodes.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-architectures-production/

Comment: why 3 config servers to run 2 shards?

Comment: @BufBills: Please read this [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-config-servers/#sharding-config-server). You always use 3 config server independently of the number of shards you have.
You could use only one, but that would be for development and/or testing purposes.

Comment: You need 3, because you need the redundancy, so if a config server craps out, your cluster is still running safely.